# How to sort a dictionary inside a dictionary based on the key(alphabetically) of the inner dictionary in python

Tags: python, django, sorting, dictionary

Despite the fact that I have seen a lot of answers about sorting a dictionary of a dictionary I was not able to adjust the solution to my problem.

Here is the structure of my dictionary:

```
OrderedDict([('2018-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 8}), ('2017-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 804,'ALFAMINO 400 GR.': 4, 'Forticare Orange/Lemon 4 X125ml': 15})])
```

The outer dictionary has as key a date in format year-month
The outer dictionary has as value a dictionary in format {'name of product: quantity}

The inner dictionary has as key the name of the product
The inner dictionary has as value the quantity(of the product)

**My aim is to sort my outer dictionary based on the latest date(the newest to be first) and my inner dictionary based on the name of the product alphabetically.**

In other words:

```
OrderedDict([('2018-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 8}),('2017-11',{'ALFAMINO 400 GR.': 4,'Forticare Orange/Lemon 4 X125ml': 15,'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 804})])
```

First goes the date 2018-11, is "newest" than 2017-11
and in inner dictionaries if I have more than one records as the dictionary with key 2017-11, first goes the ALFAMINO (starts with A), then the Forticare (starts with F) and so on..

Here is my code:

```
def warehouse_pending_products(request):
    template_name= 'warehouse/warehouse_pending_products.html'
    pendingOrdersResult={}
    pendingOrdersList=Order.objects.filter(finished=0)
    for order in pendingOrdersList:
        orderYear=order.invoice_date.year
        orderMonth=order.invoice_date.month
        orderDate=str(orderYear)+'-'+str(orderMonth)

        orderProductsWithoutSerials=ProductSerialNumbers.objects.filter(snumber__isnull=True).filter(order=order.id)#order_by('product__name')
        if orderDate in pendingOrdersResult:
            for op in orderProductsWithoutSerials:
                p_name=op.product.name.encode("utf-8")
                if p_name in pendingOrdersResult[orderDate]:


                    pendingOrdersResult[orderDate][p_name]+=1 
                else:

                    pendingOrdersResult[orderDate][p_name]=1
        else:
            if orderProductsWithoutSerials:
                pendingOrdersResult[orderDate]={}
                for op in orderProductsWithoutSerials:
                    p_name=op.product.name.encode("utf-8")
                    if p_name in pendingOrdersResult[orderDate]:
                        pendingOrdersResult[orderDate][p_name]+=1
                    else:
                        pendingOrdersResult[orderDate][p_name]=1


    result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(pendingOrdersResult.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (pendingOrdersResult[k])))
```

My dictionary is the pendingOrdersResult.

The `result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(pendingOrdersResult.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (pendingOrdersResult[k])))`
**gives wrong result.**

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the difference between the expected and perceived result as well? Helping is easier if one "see" the difference instead of a simple "does not work".

Comment: @ChristianB. I added a picture in order to be more clear. In my initial dictionary I put a part of my data not all, because the dictionary is large. For example I want the first date to be 2019-5 and not 2018-9 and also in 2019-3 dictionary I want first to appear the ALFAMINO and not the BETAQUIL. I want the appearence of products to be with the order A, B, C...

Comment: additionally there is a huge amount of code repetition. Trying to write "clean and short" code can help solving and avoiding problems. E.g. the "for op in orderProductsWithoutSerials:" loop happens twice. So basically the code starting with the first if can be mostlikely boiled down to: `order = pendingOrdersResult.setdefault(orderDate,dict())
for op in orderProductsWithoutSerials:
    p_name=op.product.name.encode("utf-8")
    order[p_name] = 1 + order.setdefault(p_name, 0)` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @ChristianB. You are not mistaken, I am not an experienced developer.

Comment: we all are learners. If I see it correctly you only sort the outer dict right now (actually you could start with standard dict and then generate the sorted versions out of it). You would have to do the same sorting for the inner dicts as well. Give this a try: (completely untested)  `for key, value in result.iteritems():
    result[key] = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(value.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): k)))`

Comment: for a "compiled" answer see below. What data type is order.invoice_date btw? datetime.date or datetime.datetime ?

Comment: @ChristianB.  invoice_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)

Comment: Then I would recommend the use of `orderDate = order.invoice_date.strftime("%y-%m")` instead of building the orderDate by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to call the `sorted` function on each of the "inner" dictionaries individually, as well as on the "outer" dictionary. You would also need to cast your inner dictionaries to have the `OrderedDict` type for them to be sortable. Here's what I could come up with, but there might be shorter/more idiomatic ways to do this:

```
# Sort the outer dictionary by key from high to low
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True))

# Sort the inner dictionaries by key
for item in d.items(): 
    d[item[0]] = OrderedDict(sorted(item[1].items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Comment: works but some dates are not sorted correctly. 2019 dates sorted right. 2018 not. For example, first appears 2018-9 then 2018-11 then 2018-1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (tested with python 3.7.1):

```
import collections

raw    = dict([('2018-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 8}), ('2017-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 804,'ALFAMINO 400 GR.': 4, 'Forticare Orange/Lemon 4 X125ml': 15})])
data   = {key : collections.OrderedDict(sorted(value.items(), key=lambda entry: entry[0])) for key, value in raw.items()}
result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda entry: entry[0]))


print(result)
```

EDIT: with a function to avoid the "c&p" code:

```
import collections

def sort_dict(unsorted):
    return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(unsorted.items(), key=lambda entry: entry[0]))

raw    = dict([('2018-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 8}), ('2017-11', {'NEOCATE JUNIOR  WITHOUT FLAVOUR 400 gr.': 804,'ALFAMINO 400 GR.': 4, 'Forticare Orange/Lemon 4 X125ml': 15})])
result = sort_dict({key : sort_dict(value) for key, value in raw.items()})

print(result)
```

Comment: works but some dates are not sorted correctly. 2019 dates sorted right. 2018 not. For example, first appears 2018-9 then 2018-11 then 2018-1

Comment: @gtopal well of course. They are strings and sorted accordingly. So either stick with datetime.datetime or format the date properly (e.g. use `order.invoice_date.strftime("%Y-%m")` )